# Redirect page using axios and node server 302 request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, axios

I am working on an app that checks the directory for any existing data, and if it's not there, the server sends a 302 redirect response to the loading page. I am using axios to make the post request on the html form to send the text to server.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="input" name="url"></input>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('inside the jquery')
      $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).find('input').val();
        console.log('is this giving us the value?', value);
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8080`, value)
      })
    })
</script>
```

The method that is executed at the post request:

```
exports.addAsset = function(res, data) {
  archive.addUrlToList(data, function(bool) {
    if (!bool) {
      res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/loading.html'});
      fetch.fetcher(data);
      res.end();

        //go to loading page
        //send that link to htmlfetcher
    }
  });
};
```

I receive the file at my client site but the browser does not render the `loading.html` file.

[Before my post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUt4d.png)

[After my post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jomkk.png)

As you can see above, the loading.html is received by the client browser, but its xhr. I know this has something to do with axios, but does anyone have a good explanation as to why this happens and/or any work-around method.

Thanks!